# Increment float exponent only

Tags: java, floating-point, bit-manipulation, java-7

I'm looking to increment the exponent of a float (without touching the mantissa) in Java.

I understand how to retrieve the exponent with `Math.getExponent()` and increment it, but am unsure about how to use bit manipulation to replace the original exponent of the float.

It doesn't like Java makes available a `getExponent()` or similar.

Note that this must increment correctly in both the negative and positive exponent range.

Comment: Your note about negative exponents is a bit strange. Do you know that exponents are represented using bias 127?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: The encoding of an exponent uses a bias. The question refers only to the actual exponent, not its encoding. E.g., the `Math.getExponent` function returns the actual exponent value. It is no more strange to refer to a negative exponent that is encoded with a bias than it is to refer to a negative integer that is encoded with two’s complement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the exponent represent the power of 2, just multiply the number by 2. That should increment the exponent (assuming that the number is normalized both before and after the multiplication). (Normalization usually happens automatically in Java, so this shouldn't be a concern unless you are doing something funny).

If you really want to manipulate the bits directly, you can use `Float.floatToIntBits` and `Float.intBitsToFloat` to convert back and forth between a `float` and an `int` view of the `float`.

Comment: What do you mean by normalize? I want to make sure the number is correctly incremented every time and that there are no rounding issues.

Comment: Damn, that was clever. +1

Comment: @DavidChouinard - Normalization ensures that the first bit (or the first implied bit) of the mantissa is not zero. In base-10 scientific notation, it's like representing 120 using 1.2E2 (normalized) in favor of 0.12E3 (not normalized). Rounding won't be an issue when multiplying by 2.

Answer (score 4):

That is really easy. Convert it to an int and increase the exponent and convert it back.
Consider this layout of a float:

[image]

Then, this code should do the trick:

```
public static float increaseExponent(float f)
{
    int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
    bits += 0x800000;
    return Float.intBitsToFloat(bits);
}
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/vs8BrG

```
float f = (float) Math.PI;
System.out.println(f);
System.out.println(f * 2.0f);
System.out.println(increaseExponent(f));
```

Outputs:

```
3.1415927
6.2831855
6.2831855
```